# How many different hybrid miners out there now that can mine bitcoin + litecoin at the same time? And where is a reliable source to buy them?

Tags: litecoin, mining-hardware

I'm looking to buy a hybrid bitcoin/litecoin miner. Which ones are reliable and where can I get them in the US?